# Yii Framework: Yii application in a root subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii, subdirectory

I'm trying to run a Yii application placed in a subfolder of the root:

```
-> public_html
----> yii_app
--------> index.php
--------> .htaccess
--------> protected
etc..
```

The application runs fine with url: http://www.site.com/yii_app
However, deeper controllers and actions redirect me to http://www.site.com
For example: http://www.site.com/yii_app/controller1/action1 will show the home page of the site.

I tried to put in the root .htaccess file rules that ignore the folder yii_app but didn't solve the problem.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/yii_app/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

Any suggestions?

Would really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to use creating url to create work urk, check this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set basePath in your config:

```
<?php
return array(
    'basePath' => 'yii_app',
    ....
);
```

Comment: I tried but gave the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CException' with message 'Application base path "yii_app" is not a valid directory.'

basePath value was set to dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',

Comment: Thats wrong, pls dont make such code without testing

Answer (score 0):

```
'basePath' => 'yii_app/protected',
```

Almost universal setting for basePath

```
'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
```

Comment: That's what I currently have in the main.php config file. However any deeper controllers and their actions take me back to the homepage. The only working controller/action is the one I set as the default.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to edit .htaccess. You just need to move the Yii entry script (index.php) and the default .htaccess up from the subdirectory to the webroot (so that they reside directly under public_html). Once you move index.php and .htaccess to the root directory, all web requests will be routed directly to index.php (rather than to the subdirectory), thus eliminating the /subdirectory part of the url.

After you move the files, you will need to edit index.php to update the references to the yii.php file (under the Yii framework directory) as well as the Yii config file (main.php). Lastly, you will need to move the assets directory to directly the webroot, since by default, Yii expects the assets directory to be located in the same location as the entry script).

That should be all you need to do, but if you need more details, I describe the approach fully here:

http://muhammadatt.tumblr.com/post/83149364519/modifying-a-yii-application-to-run-from-a-subdirectory